# sshfs mount on login with systemd and unmount on last logout

Tags: systemd, mount, login, sshfs, ssh-agent

I'd like to mount (with sshfs) my documents directory - as unprivileged user - on first login and unmount it on last logout (not every logout, of course).

I have key-based authentication working already.

Answer (score 0):

As an unprivileged user, it is not possible to use systemd, but there are easier solutions. One possible solution would be the following:

If you are using bash, include the following at the end of your ~/.profile:

```
if [ $(ps aux|grep "sshfs sshfs_user"|wc -l) -eq 1 ]; then
    # Not mounted thus mount
    sshfs sshfs_user@sshfs_server:/remote_path $HOME/mount_point
fi

logout()
{
if [ $(ps aux|grep your_user|grep bash|wc -l) -eq 1 ]; then
    # Last shell thus umount
    umount $HOME/mount_point
    unset -f logout
    logout
fi
}
```

This will check if sshfs is already run by your user and mount your documents remote folder with sshfs only once.

Replace `sshfs_user@sshfs_server:/remote_path $HOME/mount_point` with your own data. Also in this line `if [ $(ps aux|grep your_user|grep bash|wc -l) -eq 1 ]; then`change **your_user** to your bash user.

If using another shell change .profile and bash with the appropiate.
i.e. for zsh change bash for zsh and .profile with .bashrc.

**Explanation:**

When you login first time, it will check if the remote sshfs is mounted. If not, it will mount it.

We create function to replace the built-in `logout`  command. This function will check if there is only one shell process running and umount the remote fs.
Then unset the replacement of `logout` in order to avoid a loop.

Comment: Can someone explain the down vote? I would appreciate. I was just trying to help.

Comment: I was hoping for something more like systemd or even pam?!...
Thanks anyway.

Comment: You said **as unprivileged user**. Not possible to use pam or systemd. Probably you meant to **configure it for an unprivileged user**.

Comment: Couldn't I use a systemd user unit (maybe a timer?...). Is there a way to start the unit at *first* user login and stop it at *last* logout?